# Unexpected Sculpt Distortion

Tags: sculpting, distort

#### The Setting

I am currently working on sculpting my first sculpt project in blender.
I created the head shape by using a square and the subsurface modifier.

#### The Issues

When I try to crease certain areas, such as behind this ear, the vertices do not move.

[image: The crease tool doesn't crease this area]

When I try to lay clay strips on certain areas of the mesh, such as the neck, there is very strange distortion that is very undesirable. The zig-zag is what I am talking about in this image:

[image]

- I am using Blender version 2.79.
- I am *not* using dynamic topology.
- I have not applied the subdivision surface modifier.
- I have applied the rotation, location and scale of the mesh.

#### Note:

I understand that applying the subsurface and then using dynamic topology will fix these issues, but I am curious if there is another way.

Comment: " if there is another way" kind of, of course another way exists. The polygons density is too low in certain areas and they start to distort too much in order to provide yet another surface changing (creasing in the 1st image). Second is what happens when unproper base mesh topology is changed much to fit desired one. Sculpt with Multires modifier and increase subdivisions gradually

Comment: @MrZak Not sure what you mean by "kind of, of course", but if I am understanding the rest of your comment, you are saying that the density is too low. For the second, you seem to say the same thing. When I increased the density the zig zag remained.

Comment: When you already have zig-zags only increasing subdivisions is quite bad cure. It will become easier if you crank up subdivisions 2 levels up - which will also create a lot of unnecessary geometry in all other areas. I was saying not only too low density - it is too low density because of incorrect base topology when you move faces to one spot and there aren't sufficient amount of them for the other spot.

Comment: @MrZak I see. Do you have any suggestions as to fixing the topology?

Comment: Fixing topology is vast topic by itself, on the already sculpted mesh in particular. You could retopo this mesh with yet another one, you could change the edge flow for the current one. Second might create distortions as well (but for another reason). What could be useful is to look at some topology examples for the head and start from there